# Python - using re.compile with re.split

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract specific data from a text file. Each line of the file has strings separated by tabs. I would like to separate each word and keep it as whole word. Is it possible to combine re.split and re.compile.findall to do this?

An example is shown below.

Original line in file:

```
Name    Charlie     Blue     Bird   ******Grade:5****** ******  ******  ******
```

Line separated by tabs:

```
['Name', 'Charlie    Blue     Bird', '******Grade:5******', '******', '******']
```

Line that I would like to have:

```
['Name', 'Charlie', 'Blue', 'Bird', 'Grade:5']
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

(Yes, the stars are meant to be there as well).

Comment: How did you get your original line into the list?

Comment: It is what the file gives.

Comment: I mean - what code did you run to get it into the list?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a single `findall` and search for the characters you're interested in.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'Name    Charlie     Blue     Bird   ******Grade:5****** ******  ******  ******  '
>>> re.findall(r'[A-Za-z0-9:]+', s)
['Name', 'Charlie', 'Blue', 'Bird', 'Grade:5']
```

Comment: Thank you! Would you mind explaining what the '[A-Za-z0-9:]+' means? For example, if I had a space in 'Grade:5' such as 'Grade:  5', would I still be able to maintain the entire word?

Comment: If it was `Grade: 5` instead of `Grade:5`, the `Grade:` and the `5` would be two separate elements in the list. You said that it was a tab-separated file, but your sample data was separated by multiple spaces. There are many other ways to approach this (`re.split` on two or more spaces, `re.split` on tabs, `str.replace` the stars, etc.), but if your actual data are different from what you posted, you'll have to correct it with an edit.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. No, the actual data should be tab-seprated, but I have no control over the actual words in the file, so if the person had decided to write *****Grade:  5****** then I would have to keep the entire word as one word and not have it separated by a space. I appreciate the comment. I think I might have to find a different way of extracting the data from the file.